# ToggleClass - very basic

Tags: toggleclass

My toggle does not work.

```
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="bkg-blue">...
```

In functions.js, I just have :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.logo').on('click',function(){
    //alert("test"); > works fine
    $("body").toggleClass("bkg-white");
    });
});
```

My bkg-white class never appears on the body.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I just removed the $(document).ready(function() at the beginning and it now works.